# Is there any way to force a model to be revalidated in an MVC3 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, controller

I have a Model which contains an Address and Person twice, once for the "main" contact, and once for the "invoice" contact, and a boolean value called InvoiceContactSameAsMain - a clumsy name, but descriptive. The getter of the property checks to see if the Address and Contact objects for "main" and "invoice" are the same, and returns true if they are. The setter checks to see if the value is true, and if so, copies the main Person over the invoice Person , and the main Address over the invoice Address.

In my View, the boolean value is represented by a check box (as you'd expect). Attached to this is a small JS function which, if the check box is checked, hides the invoice fields and "switches off" the client-side validation by setting the data-val HTML attribute to false and forcing a re-parse of the unobtrusive validation attributes in the form. Un-checking the box naturally shows the fields and turns the validation back on.

All of this works fine, until I get to my Controller.

Despite the Model being "valid" and containing the correct fields (thanks to my InvoiceContactSameAsMain setter), ModelState.IsValid remains resolutely false, and I can't seem to find any way to revalidate the model. If I clear the ModelState, any and all errors disappear. I'd very much rather avoid digging through the fields in the ModelState by name, as the Person and Address objects are used throughout the project and may need to change or be extended at some point.

Is there something obvious I've missed here that will allow me to revalidate the ModelState? I've tried TryUpdateModel and TryValidateModel, but they both appear to use the cached ModelState values. I've even tried recursively calling my Action again, passing in the "fixed" model. I'm almost thankful that one didn't work.

Please let me know if any more detail or examples will help.

Edit: Obviously, if this is completely the wrong way to approach the problem, just let me know.

Edit 2: Added code samples as per Ron Sijm's suggestion.

The model is as follows:
    public class Details
    {
        public int? UserID { get; set; }

```
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public Address CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public Person MainPerson { get; set; }

    public Address InvoiceAddress { get; set; }
    public Person InvoiceContact { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Promotional code")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Promotional code should not exceed 20 characters")]
    public string PromotionalCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Invoice contact same as main")]
    public bool InvoiceContactSameasMain
    {
        get { return InvoiceContact.Equals(MainPerson); }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                InvoiceContact = MainPerson.Copy();
                InvoiceAddress = CompanyAddress.Copy();
            }
        }
    }

    [_Common.MustAccept]
    [Display(Name = "I agree with the Privacy Policy")]
    public bool PrivacyFlag { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Please subscribe to Sodexo News Letter")]
    public bool MarketingOption { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contract number")]
    public int? ContractNumber { get; set; }

    public Details()
    {
        Company = new Company();
        CompanyAddress = new Address();
        MainPerson = new Person();
        InvoiceAddress = new Address();
        InvoiceContact = new Person();
    }
}
```

This is wrapped in a ViewModel as there are a number of SelectLists involved in the page:

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public Details    Details              { get; set; }
    public SelectList MainContactTitles    { get; set; }
    public SelectList InvoiceContactTitles { get; set; }
    public SelectList SICCodes             { get; set; }
    public SelectList TypesOfBusiness      { get; set; }
    public SelectList NumbersOfEmployees    { get; set; }

    public DetailsViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

The Controller's two relevant actions are as follows:

```
public class DetailsController : _ClientController
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DetailsViewModel viewModel = new DetailsViewModel();
        if (Client == null)
        {
            viewModel.Details = DetailsFunctions.GetClient((int)UserId, null);
        }
        else
        {
             viewModel.Details = DetailsFunctions.GetClient((int)UserId, Client.ContractNumber);
        }
        viewModel.MainContactTitles = DetailsFunctions.GetTitles((int)UserId, viewModel.Details.MainPerson.title);
        viewModel.InvoiceContactTitles = DetailsFunctions.GetTitles((int)UserId, viewModel.Details.InvoiceContact.title);
        viewModel.SICCodes = DetailsFunctions.GetSICCodes(viewModel.Details.Company.sic_code);
        viewModel.NumbersOfEmployees = DetailsFunctions.GetNumbersOfEmployees(viewModel.Details.Company.number_of_employees);
        viewModel.TypesOfBusiness = DetailsFunctions.GetTypesOfBusiness(viewModel.Details.Company.public_private);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DetailsViewModel ViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //go to main page for now
            DetailsFunctions.SetClient((int)UserId, ViewModel.Details);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewModel.MainContactTitles = DetailsFunctions.GetTitles((int)UserId, ViewModel.Details.MainPerson.title);
            ViewModel.InvoiceContactTitles = DetailsFunctions.GetTitles((int)UserId, ViewModel.Details.InvoiceContact.title);
            ViewModel.SICCodes = DetailsFunctions.GetSICCodes(ViewModel.Details.Company.sic_code);
            ViewModel.NumbersOfEmployees = DetailsFunctions.GetNumbersOfEmployees(ViewModel.Details.Company.number_of_employees);
            ViewModel.TypesOfBusiness = DetailsFunctions.GetTypesOfBusiness(ViewModel.Details.Company.public_private);
            return View(ViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

I can provide the view and JS if needs be, but as the Model binding is all working just fine, I'm not sure how much help that is.

Comment: I think a code sample of what you have would help

Comment: You can see why the `ModelState.IsValid` is false when debugging. If you expand some nodes you will see which rule(s) failed.

Comment: @Darcy: The rules which are failing are those in the copied-over Invoice Address and Person. The validator still sees them as blank, even though I can see them filled in correctly in the model.

Comment: I've just tried turning my "Invoice contact same as main" logic on its head: it's now a simple boolean value, and the getters for invoice contact and invoice address check it and return the main contact (or address) if the boolean value is true.

This had no effect on the problem, and the ModelState still thinks those fields are empty, even though the Model shows them quite clearly as filled in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a moderately crap hack, but I've ended up just clearing the ModelState errors for the relevant fields in the controller before checking ModelState.IsValid:

```
if(ViewModel.Details.InvoiceContactSameasMain)
        {
            //iterate all ModelState values, grabbing the keys we want to clear errors from
            foreach (string Key in ModelState.Keys)
            {
                if (Key.StartsWith("Details.InvoiceContact") || Key.Startwith("Details.InvoiceAddress"))
                {
                    ModelState[Key].Errors.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
```

The only upside is, if the Person or Address objects change, this code won't need to be altered.

Comment: +1 this is the only thing resembling a working solution I've found for a very similar problem.  Seems like there should be a better way but I don't know what it is.